# Google Sheets HTML data input, can't get it to populate

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Spreadsheet:[image]

The html data entry:

[image]

I have been working on this for 8 hours, I cannot figure it out.

I have a **website** that I am uploading items to be sold.  I have a Google sheet that I am keeping track of this information.  We will have probably over 3,000 items to sell, so this html would be a lifesaver!

I however cannot get it to populate into my Google sheets.  It runs, I don't get error messages, it just won't populate in my sheet.

This is my sheet, it is open

I am teaching myself how to do the website myself, I only have about 3 or 4 months under my belt. Any help would be WONDERFUL!

**Code GS**

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate();
}

/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url =
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uF5YBKyfVxvrA4QrUuRqHrxe7C1qEySIxAL_r-PkBIQ/edit#gid=1180254005";

  function processForm(formObject) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

    ws.appendRow([
      formObject.location,
      formObject.itemNumber,
      formObject.name,
      formObject.description,
      formObject.price,
      formObject.markedDown,
      formObject.pricePaid,
      formObject.category,
      formObject.sold,
      formObject.postedOnline,
    ]);
  }
}
```

**Index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
          <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center font-weight-bold">Seattle Bound Data</p>
          <!-- Row 1 -->
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 font-weight-bold">
              <label for="first_name">Location</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 font-weight-bold">
              <label for="itemNumber">Item Number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemNumber" name="itemNumber" placeholder="Item Number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 font-weight-bold">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Row 1 -->
          <!-- Row 2 -->
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-12 font-weight-bold">
              <label for="description">Description</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description">
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- Row 2 -->
          <!-- Row 3 -->
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 font-weight-bold">
              <label for="price">Price</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" placeholder="$00.00">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4 font-weight-bold">
              <label for="markedDown">Marked Down</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="markedDown" name="markedDown" placeholder="$00.00">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group col-md-4 font-weight-bold">
              <label for="pricePaid">Price Paid</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="pricePaid" name="pricePaid" placeholder="$0.00">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Row 3 -->
          <!-- Row 4 -->
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">
              <label for="categories">Categories</label>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <select name="categories">
                  <option value="media">Media</option>
                  <option value="tools">Tools</option>
                  <option value="clothes">Clothes</option>
                  <option value="bears">Bears</option>
                  <option value="misc">Misc</option>
                  <option value="electronics">Electronics</option>
                </select>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">
                  <p>Sold</p>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sold" id="true" value="true">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="true">True</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sold" id="false" value="false">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="false">False</label>
                  </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group col-sm-6 font-weight-bold">
                  <p>Posted Online</p>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="postedOnline" id="true" value="true">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="true">True</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="postedOnline" id="false" value="false">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="false">False</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div id="output"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>


</html>
```

**JavaScript.html**

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
      
      
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
  
</script>
```

Comment: Provide [mcve] -  Everything needed to answer your question(including code and sample data) should be in the question  itself. Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). You may also try the [Blank sheet maker here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383).

Comment: You need to give some information. We can't help with what you have written. All you have written is "Please help me".

Comment: It works for me as a dialog

Comment: It won't work on a normal hosted website because google.script.run is only meant to be used for google webapps or dialogs

Comment: I am not using it on my website, this is just for me to keep track of what I have got pictures taken and where everything is.

Comment: You have a function processForm inside a function processForm. This appears to be an error. The inner function is never called.

Comment: FWIW, A Google form would be easier.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run the code but with few corrections.

1. In app script, inside the `pocessForm()` function you are again declaring a new function with the same name, which is unnecessary and your code does not run because of this. So you should remove the outer function and just keep inner one.
2. When you deploy your app, the `activeSheet` function does not work. Instead, use
   `SpreadsheetApp.openById("")`
   and give the id of the spreadsheet which you can find in the link of the spreadsheet. These will be the alphanumeric character string. For your sheet it's this - "1uF5YBKyfVxvrA4QrUuRqHrxe7C1qEySIxAL_r-PkBIQ".

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}

/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(formObject));
  // var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // incorrect
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName('Data');

  ws.appendRow([formObject.location,
  formObject.itemNumber,
  formObject.name,
  formObject.description,
  formObject.price,
  formObject.markedDown,
  formObject.pricePaid,
  formObject.category,
  formObject.sold,
  formObject.postedOnline]);

}
```

And this works.

Suggestion - You may want to handle the form validation. Currently, if a user submits the form with any empty field, app script throws error. Easy way to handle this is by making each input field required in html.

Comment: Thank you SO much, it finally works! This will save me hours!!